# Can filebeat output to other application

Tags: filebeat

The filebeat can be set to output to elasticsearch, logstash, file or console. Is it possible that filebeat can be input source for other application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the output possibilities of filebeat as per the latest release:

1. Elastic
2. Logstash
3. Kafka
4. Redis
5. File
6. Console
7. Cloud

But filebeat is an open source agent. You can create a plugin of your own to suit the needs of your application.